# Google Script for PDF image/screenshot import into Google Doc

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

I'm trying to write a script that takes images from a PDF file and puts them into a Google Doc Template. The PDF has a bunch of images in it, one image per page. What I want to do is grab the images one at a time (or take a screenshot of the entire page) and paste it into a new document. How can I access a single image at a time to import it into the google doc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no way to play directly with a pdf file but you should consider to first convert these pdf to google docs and, in a second time, use the [document class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_document?hl=fr-FR) that can retrieve images inside the doc quite easily...

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that you could convert a PDF into a google doc. It worked perfectly.